# Javascript can't access array from one file to another

Tags: javascript, php

In my php page, i'm including 2 .js files, and the first one creates and populates a js array which I need to access in the second .js file.  For some reason, I'm getting an error that the array is undefined when I know for a fact that it's being populated.  Why is this broken?
What am I doing wrong?

```
Error: ReferenceError: sl is not defined
```

first.js

```
var sl = [];
for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
    options += '<option value="' + j[i].value + '">' + j[i].text + '</option>';
    sl[j[i].value] = [];
    sl[j[i].value]['shopping_list'] = j[i].text;
    sl[j[i].value]['is_private']= j[i].is_private;
    console.log('printing SL for ' + j[i].value);
    console.log(sl[j[i].value]['shopping_list']);
}
```

second.js

```
$("#shopping_list_name").val(sl[$("#existing_shopping_lists").val()]['shopping_list']);
```

Comment: Where is 'sl' defined? Is it in the global scope? If so, are you sure the second.js is getting evaluated second? JavaScript interrupts in order (top to bottom) so attempting to reference a variable declared below will throw an error.

Comment: Make sure that second.js is in fact being included AFTER first.js.

Comment: If the user is logged in from the beginning, it's defined and populated when the php page loads.  But they can login after the page is loaded through jquery, then sl is declared and loaded in first.js on success of login

Comment: how do you ensure the order?  other than just top to bottom?

Comment: oh, and the logic within second.js is fired on a click event so the logic in first.js is definitely happening first

Comment: Is the code that you cited from `first.js` inside a function (possibly a `$(function() {});`)? JavaScript has functional scoping making the `var sl=[]` not global (regardless of order)

Comment: @JasonSperske Yes! In first.js, it's within a $(document).ready(function(){ and a .validate submithandler.  How do i fix it so that I can access the array in second.js?  Nevermind!  I declared it where the php was writing it and it's FIXED!!!!!  Please submit your answer and I'll choose it.  Yay for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the code that you cited from first.js inside a function (possibly a `$(function() {});`)? JavaScript has functional scoping making the `var sl=[]` not global (regardless of order)

Comment: Yes, the issue was in regards to scope.  Once I declared the array outside of any functions, I was able to populate and reference it successfully everywhere that I needed to.  I really appreciate your quick help!